# Update Testset (add test cases to test set) with Rally API 2.0

Tags: rally

I'm stumped. trying to add test cases to a testset.  The call completes successfully but only adds One test case to the test set.

```
$url = https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/{$apiVersion}/TestSet/{$testSetObjectID}?key={$securityToken}
```

My payload:

```
 {
    "TestSet": {
        "TestCases": [{
            "_ref": "/TestCase/17905298381",
            "_ref": "/TestCase/10610152170",
            "_ref": "/TestCase/10610171280"
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from browser REST client that adds four test cases to a test set:

endpoint:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testset/14469862335/testcases/add?key=fbaa0c04-...
```

Payload:

```
{
    "CollectionItems": [
    {"_ref": "/testcase/14469885324"},
    {"_ref": "/testcase/14469885842"},
    {"_ref": "/testcase/14469886070"},
    {"_ref": "/testcase/14469887154"}
]
}
```

See also [Collections in WS API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/rest_collections.jsp).